# Can I register a custom URL Scheme/Protocol with a Node HTTP Server?

Tags: node.js, http, url-scheme

I would like to be able to handle a custom URL scheme with the Node HTTP API. I would like to write links inside web pages like this: `app://foo/bar`. I would like to have the Node HTTP Request Handler receive this kind of URL.

When I try this kind of custom protocol in my URL, it looks like Chrome is not sending out the request because it is malformed. So nothing gets to my HTTP server in Node.

Is it possible to bind your HTTP server to a custom URL Scheme or Protocol like `app://foo/bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain protocols such as `http://` and `https://` will be sent to your nodejs http server.  That's the issue.  Your node.js server is an http server.  The chrome browser will only send it URLs with the http protocol that it knows belong to an http server.

A custom protocol has to be first handled in the browser with a browser add-on that can then decide what to do with it.

---

Perhaps what you want to do is a custom HTTP URL such as:

```
http://yourserver.com/foo/bar
```

Then, your node.js http server will get the `/foo/bar` part of the request and you can write custom handlers for that.

---

To recap, the first part of the URL the part before the `://` is the protocol.  That tells the browser what protocol this URL is supposed to be used with.  Without a browser add-on, a browser only comes with support for some built-in protocols such as `http`, `https`, `ws`, `wss`, `mailto` and some others.

An http server will only be able to respond to the http protocol so it will only work with URLs that expect to use the http protocol and that the browser knows use the http protocol.  Thus your own protocol that the browser does not know about is not something the browser knows what to do with.  It would take a browser add-on to tell the browser what to do for a custom URL.

> When I try this kind of url, it almost looks like Chrome is batting it down before it can get to my HTTP server in Node.

Yes, it's not a recognizable protocol built into the browser so the browser doesn't know what to do with it or how to speak that protocol.

> Is it possible to bind your HTTP server to a custom URL Scheme like this?

Only with a browser add-on that registers and implements support for the custom URL protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with using `http://yourserver.com` is the browser will try to fetch it from `yourserver.com` and not look on my local server. What I'm trying to do is provide a custom protocol or route that can handle content that is outside of root. I understand the security implications. What does work is using unsafe chars, IE: `{APP}path/to/foo.css` and I can then resolve `{APP}` to an out-of-root path. I'm using this to route internal app resources to a page.

Comment: @f1lt3r - I don't understand what that comment means.  I answered your original question here, but if you want to describe the problem you're really trying to solve (not the way you thought of solving it) in a new question, then we can take a look at that problem description.  A node.js server can convert an incoming URL request to ANY file on your server.  This is not like some other web servers where static files have to have a direct correlation between URL paths and file system paths.  There's no restriction at all in node.js.  Files can be anywhere on your server.

Comment: @f1lt3r - Just use safe chars in your URL such as `/public/too/foo.css` and then have your server convert `/public` to whatever the real path is on your server.  Say you're real path on the server is `/private/web`.   You can just create a route for `/public` and anything that comes after, you attach onto `/private/web` so when your server gets a request for `/public/to/foo.css`, it converts that to `/private/web/to/foo.css` and serves that file.  If you're using Express as your framework, `express.static()` can even do that for you.

Comment: I understand that I can (and do) serve files from anywhere. I was simply hoping to do the work via a custom protocol to segregate requests. I can not use regular paths like `public/` in my case because the software I'm working on is an OpenSource server designed explicitly for localhost. I don't want to prohibit my users from using `public/` by gobbling it up myself for the app internals.

Comment: @f1lt3r - Well, you HAVE to use an actual path segment that is legal in a URL.  I'd advise that you either just reserve your own path segment (or make it configurable by the customer) or pick some characters for it that are legal in a URL, but not commonly used in the file system.  This is how web servers work.

Answer (score 2):

I have made an npm module for this purpose.

link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-registry

So to do this in nodejs you just need to run the code below:

First Install it

```
npm i protocol-registry
```

Then use the code below to register you entry file.

```js
const path = require('path');

const ProtocolRegistry = require('protocol-registry');

console.log('Registering...');
// Registers the Protocol
ProtocolRegistry.register({
    protocol: 'testproto', // sets protocol for your command , testproto://**
    command: `node ${path.join(__dirname, './index.js')} $_URL_`, // $_URL_ will the replaces by the url used to initiate it
    override: true, // Use this with caution as it will destroy all previous Registrations on this protocol
    terminal: true, // Use this to run your command inside a terminal
    script: false
}).then(async () => {
    console.log('Successfully registered');
});
```

Then suppose someone opens testproto://test
then a new terminal will be launched executing :

```
node yourapp/index.js testproto://test
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment thread on the other answer, I think I understand what you're trying to do.

I hear that you want to serve some files off `localhost` but not at all pollute the namespace of an existing webserver.

I have several weird alternative solutions:

1. Just pick a namespace that's unlikely to be used by a user. You can start with an underscore or a dollar sign? Or you can just a very random number.
2. You can serve your files, but only if a URI parameter exists with a very random string. PHP does this to serve the PHP logo for example.
3. You can't really change the scheme without creating browser add-ons, but you *do* have control over the TCP port. You can start a second webserver on a second port.
4. You can use a second domain. Just register a domain and point an A record to 127.0.0.1. Now your webserver running on localhost can check out the `Host:` header and serve your files if it matches your special hostname.